# pika rabbitmq python 3.6

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to use pika to connect with rabbitmq

```
def get_connection():
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(MQ_USER, MQ_PASS)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(MQ_SERVER, 5672, '/', credentials))
    return connection
```

I can use those credentials with rabbitmqctl, the output is something like this:

```
# rabbitmqctl authenticate_user user pass
Authenticating user "user" ...
Success
```

I have also tried to just use strings with the values inside the function and get the same error. I also have telnet access on the rabbitmq port and the user has access to the channel.

When execute the python code I get this error:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/analysis/stream/finish/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/path/to/api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/path/to/api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/path/to/api/core/views.py", line 2465, in record_finsh
    inform_process(video.filename)
  File "/path/to/api/core/views.py", line 702, in inform_process
    con = get_connection()
  File "/path/to/api/base/rabitmq.py", line 7, in get_connection
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=MQ_SERVER, port=5672, virtual_host='/', credentials=credentials))
  File "/path/to/api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 360, in __init__
    self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
  File "/path/to/api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError
```

It looks to me like something happens on this line `credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(MQ_USER, MQ_PASS)` even when the error in on the next line. What does this function do exactly? Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:
I said I think the error is on this line `credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(MQ_USER, MQ_PASS)` because if I add something like:

```
def get_connection():
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(MQ_USER, MQ_PASS)
    exit()
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(MQ_SERVER, 5672, '/', credentials))
    return connection
```

I still get more or less the same error:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/analysis/stream/finish/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/path/to/api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/path/to/api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/path/to/api/core/views.py", line 2465, in record_finsh
    inform_process(video.filename)
  File "/path/to/api/core/views.py", line 702, in inform_process
    con = get_connection()
  File "/path/to/api/base/rabitmq.py", line 7, in get_connection
    return 0
  File "/path/to/api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 360, in __init__
    self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
  File "/path/to/api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError
```

Because of this I also tried replacing with actual values like `credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('user', 'mq@pass')` and also get the same result.

EDIT2: Answering to the comments bellow.

```
def get_connection():
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('user', 'mq@passwd')
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('172.x.y.z', 5672, '/', credentials))
    return connection
```

Returns the same issue. Rabbit MQ runs on remote IP. I already tested and I can telnet to the IP.

Comment: Providing wrong set of credentials to `pika.PlainCredentials` will not produce this error. The credentials will not be validated until a socket connection is opened with the RabbitMQ server.

Comment: Try replacing all your variables with the actual values

Comment: Already replaced. Get the same. I will give it a second try, but I already tested.

Comment: Please check out edit 2. This alsi returns the same.

Answer (score 0):

`pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError` is raised when the `host` is not reachable by pika.

In case of invalid credentials, pika raises:

`pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosedByBroker: (403, 'ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.')`

for invalid virtual host:

`pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosedByBroker: (530, 'NOT_ALLOWED - vhost / not found')`

Check if the `host` or `port` value provided is valid.

Reference: [pika docs](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/adapters/blocking.html)

Comment: Hi bumblebee, I think this error can mean something else to, because If I add `exit()`  or `return 0` right after the `credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(MQ_USER, MQ_PASS)` line then the error is on the exit or return line. I will add an edit on this regard with more details.